# help me find the value of a when u=(a,-4) and v=(2,6) are parallel vectors.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces, vector-fields, scalar-fields

u=(a,-4) and v=(2,6) are parallel vectors. to find the value of a, I let -4=6k and the find the value of k=-2/3. I multiplied 2, the x component of vector v, with the value of k to get the value of a. 2*-2/3=-4/3. so a=-4/3.

Comment: If it's vectors from the origin they are only parallel when they are collinear. In that case you take the extent by which the y value of $\vec v$ is scaled to $\vec u$, $-2\over3$ and apply it on the x coordinate. I guess then your reasoning is correct, but it would be more fun to consider them as translations instead

Comment: Yes, a= -4/3 is correct.